# NPM error on installing react-native-elements

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, webpack, react-native-elements

I want to install `react-native-elements` for my app, but after entering the install command in the cmd prompt, it gives this error :

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...webpack-loader":"^3.3'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-11T06_21_21_206Z-debug.log
```

And in `2020-04-11T06_21_21_206Z-debug.log`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   'react-native-elements' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose npm-session 19d809f3b42b5934
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-elements 656ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-native-elements@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...webpack-loader":"^3.3'
9 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...webpack-loader":"^3.3'
9 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
9 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
9 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
9 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
9 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
10 verbose cwd E:\Project\test
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-native-elements"
13 verbose node v8.11.1
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...webpack-loader":"^3.3'
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

All other libraries are installing successfully. Only `react-native-elements` is giving error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then install react-native-elements

```
npm install react-native-elements
```

Answer (score 4):

Try installing an older version of react-native-elements.

I resolved this issue by installing the 3.0.0 version, using `npm install react-native-elements@3.0.0`.

By doing just `npm install react-native-elements` (without the fixed version), npm was trying to install version 3.3.2 of react-native-elements.

Another option is to use the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag:

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

or

`npm install react-native-elements --legacy-peer-deps`